# bash: list files by mask and avoid unmatched masks

Tags: bash, globbing

There is my script (simplified):

```
cd /etc; for f in *.{conf,cfg,foo}; do echo $f; done
```

It outputs something like

```
adduser.conf
apg.conf
...
vdpau_wrapper.cfg
*.foo
```

(just an example)

Just for now I using something like

```
for f in *.{conf,cfg,foo}; do test -f $f && echo $f; done
```

because of `*.foo` (no files matched to the mask)

Is there any more convenient solution (e.g. do not list `*.ext` if no such files found)?

In other words: I want to avoid `*.foo` line in the output when no files matched to the `*.foo` mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Disable it again using:

```
shopt -u nullglob
```

If you're writing a shell function that needs to unconditionally enable or disable a shopt setting temporarily and then revert back to whatever the previous state was, you could do:

```
oldshopt=$(shopt -p)
shopt -s nullglob
<do stuff...>
eval "$oldshopt"
```

There is also the opposite option, `failglob`, which causes an error message whenever a glob expansion fails.